# Prove that $\sup_{x,x'\in\mathsf{X}} |f(x) - f(x')| = 2 \inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}} |f - c|_\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that $\sup_{x,x'\in\mathsf{X}} |f(x) - f(x')| = 2 \inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}} |f - c|_\infty$ where $f$ is a bounded function on $X$ and $|f|_\infty = \sup_{x\in\mathsf{X}} |f(x)|$.

The steps I followed: I wrote the supremum as,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x'\in \mathsf{X}} \sup_{x\in \mathsf{X}} |f(x) - f(x')|
\end{align*}
so essentially I have,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x'\in \mathsf{X}} |f - f(x')|_\infty
\end{align*}
But I couldn't see how to continue to to an infimum and with a $2$ factor. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own answer. I'd be grateful if someone points out a flaw. It is a bit long, I think that it can be made shorter.

**Left hand side**. Starting from the left hand side. We see that for all $x,x'\in\mathsf{X}$, we have straightforwardly (I omit $\mathsf{X}$ from the notation),
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(x')| &= \max\{f(x) - f(x'),f(x')-f(x)\} \\ &\leq \max\{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x), \sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)\}
\end{align*}
for all $x,x'$, hence,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x,x'} |f(x) - f(x')| \leq \sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)
\end{align*}
For the other direction, choose $x,x'$ s.t. $f(x) \geq \sup_x f(x) - \epsilon/2$ and $f(x') \leq \inf_x f(x) + \epsilon/2$. Then,
$$|f(x) - f(x')| \geq \sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x) - \epsilon$$
Taking $\sup$ of LHS preserves the inequality, $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, hence we have the other direction $\sup_{x,x'} |f(x) - f(x')| \geq \sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)$. So we have shown,
$$\sup_{x,x'} |f(x) - f(x')| =\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)$$
**Right hand side**. The strategy here is to show that,
\begin{align*}
\inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}} \sup_x |f(x) - c| = \frac{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)}{2}.
\end{align*}
For $\leq$ direction, pick $c_\star = \frac{\sup_x f(x) + \inf_x f(x)}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - c_\star| &= \max\{f(x) - c_\star, c_\star - f(x)\} \\
&\leq \max\{\sup_x f(x) - c_\star, c_\star - \inf_x f(x)\} \\
&=\frac{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)}{2}
\end{align*}
True for also $\sup$. Since it is true for $c_\star$, infimum should be at least smaller, so we have,
\begin{align*}
\inf_c \sup_x |f(x) - c_\star| &\leq \frac{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)}{2}
\end{align*}
For $\geq$ direction, we have,
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - c| \geq \min\{f(x)-c,c-f(x)\}
\end{align*}
Take supremums of both sides over $x$,
\begin{align*}
\sup_x |f(x) - c| \geq \min \{\sup_x f(x) - c, c - \inf_x f(x)\}
\end{align*}
If $c \geq c_\star$, then,
\begin{align*}
\sup_x |f(x) - c| \geq \sup_x f(x) - c\geq \frac{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)}{2}
\end{align*}
but if $c \leq c_\star$, then
\begin{align*}
\sup_x |f(x) - c| \geq c - \inf_x f(x) \geq \frac{\sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x)}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Approximate the term on the left by $|f(a) - f(b)|$ and set $c = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$. Similarly, approximate the term on the right by $f(a) - c$ and $c-f(b)$ for the other direction.

Comment: thanks! but $c - f(b)$ direction works for this special $c_\star = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$, however, it is not very apparent to see it for the infimum over $c\in\mathbb{R}$. (i.e. to see that it holds for both $c\geq c_\star$ and $c\leq c_\star$.)

Comment: Choose $a, b, c$ so that $\inf \|f - c\|_\infty \le \min\{f(a) - c, c - f(b)\} + \varepsilon$.

Comment: I was stuck for the other direction, indeed.